# POST JSON to mysql from Swift 3

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, swift

I am trying to post from swift 3 to mysql via php file, the file is connected to the mysql database successfully, but when I post from the app I get this error on the console 
please advise,

> 2017-07-12 19:10:42.547105+0300 Testing JSON[19854:1541531] [] nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9807]
>   2017-07-12 19:10:42.548 Testing JSON[19854:1541842] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
>   error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
>       "",
>       ""
>   ), NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005ac70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
>       "",
>       ""
>   )}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://techdrops.co/JSON/store.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://techdrops.co/JSON/store.php, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})

Comment: *"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made"* Looks like you need to fix your certificates.

Comment: you mean apple certificates !

Comment: Are you using http or https?

Comment: I used both and got the same error

Comment: Please review [these search results on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=An+SSL+error+has+occurred+and+a+secure+connection+to+the+server+cannot+be+made+%27-9802%27).